# Dereferencing Pointer in Dynamic Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have two arrays, each initialised as follows:

```
struct file_descriptor *list1 = (struct file_descriptor *)malloc(4096 * sizeof(struct file_descriptor));

struct file_descriptor *list2 = (struct file_descriptor *)malloc(4096 * sizeof(struct file_descriptor));
```

Each array is essentially a list of `struct file_descriptor` pointers.

Now `list1` already has a pointers in the array (that point to `struct file_descriptor`'s), and I need to have the same indices in `list2` point to the same objects that `list1` pointers point to. So if `list1[2] = some_object`, I'm trying to point `list2[2] = some_object` as well.

So:

```
int i;
for(i = 3; i < 4096; i++) {
    struct file_descriptor *parent_fd = &list1[i]; // points to the struct that element at i points to in list1
    list2[i] = parent_fd;
}
```

At line 2 in the loop, this throws a:
`incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct file_descriptor’ from type ‘struct file_descriptor *’` error.

Obviously, that's because `list2[i]` is the actual `struct file_descriptor`, and not the pointer in the `list2` which points to that struct. Changing it to `&list2[i] = parent_fd;` also throws an error because `&list2[i]` is not an lvalue.

How would I dereference the pointer in the array at index `i`, so that `list2[i]` points to `*list1[i]`

Comment: Actually, based on your code, each array is a list of `struct file_descriptors` not pointers to such structs (I am not sure if that's what you meant). Anyway, it seems the issue has something to do with the `open_files` member--would it be possible to display the `struct file_descriptor` declaration?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake from copying from my real code. See my changes. How would I make each array a list of pointers to `struct file_descriptors`? Would I change it to: `struct file_descriptor **list1 = (struct file_descriptor **)malloc(4096 * sizeof(struct file_descriptor *));`?

Comment: Yes, that would be how to change it to a list of pointers.

Comment: @Darksky It's very simple Darksky.Look at my answer.You simply use `for(i=0;i<=4096;i++) list2[i]=list1[i];` When the pointers in `list2` are assigned the values of the respective pointers in `list1`,those pointers in `list2` will point to the same variables as the pointers in `list1` when dereferenced, won't they? `*list1[i]` are nothing but variables of type `struct file_descriptor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list1` and `list2` are of type `struct file_descriptor **` not `struct file_descriptor *`.

Further, don't **declare** a `struct file_descriptor` pointer or variable *inside* a loop.

Anyways,if you want the pointers in `list2` to point to the same structure variables as the respective pointers in `list1` do,then it's fairly simple.You do it as:

```
 for(i=0;i<=4096;i++)
 list2[i]=list1[i];
```

Further, if you intend your arrays to be arrays of `pointers` to the the structure variables, instead of arrays of structure variables, then you should use the following:

```
   malloc(4096 * sizeof(struct file_descriptor*));  //note the second *
```

**Edit** Your line `list2[i] = parent_fd;` shows type mismatch because you have declared `list2` as of type `struct file_descriptor*` and hence `list2[i]` is of type `struct file_descriptor`, while `parent_fd` is of type `struct file_descriptor*`.In simple words,the left side of the `=` is a struct variable while the right side is a pointer to a struct variable. Like I said, you should declare `list1` and `list2` as type `struct file_descriptor**` not `struct file_descriptor*`.That should deal with the warning you encountered.

Comment: Sorry I added open_files in my code when I shouldn't. Please see what I have now. I did exactly what you said (as I said in the question) and it does not work. I'm writing a kernel, I cannot post my entire "program" here.

Comment: While this is technically correct, I find the wording a little misleading: as it stands `list1, list2` are indeed of type `struct file_descriptor *`. Do you mean they *should* be of type `struct file_descriptor **`? Also, I'm curious as to why you say "don't declare ... inside a loop"? While it is a bit redundant in this case, there is no harm in doing so--and definitely no harm in **declaring** variables inside a loop in general.

Comment: @voidptr The OP says he intends the two lists to be arrays of **pointers**,hence they **must** be of type `struct file_descriptor**`,since `list1` and `list2` are pointers.

Comment: `struct file_descriptor **` fixes it. The `*` in `struct file_descriptor *` blinded me for a bit thinking it's an array of pointers. For the declaration inside the loop, I actually aren't doing so. But I put it there for the sake of the question; it's a small detail that does not require optimisation.